# Python error in file encode

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, encode

I got some problem with file encode. Its working, but problem is when I'm going to parse by BS4 encoded file.

```
# encoding: utf-8
import codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f1 = codecs.open("1.txt", "r", "utf-8")
text = f1.read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(text.encode('utf-8'))
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    zeit = tr.find('td', class_='zeit').get_text(strip=True)
    system = tr.find('td', class_='system').get_text(strip=True)
    fehlertext = tr.find('td', class_='fehlertext').get_text(strip=True)
    print zeit, system, fehlertext


Result: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
-bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Try enocding ascii and ignoring the errors. encode('ascii', 'ignore')

Comment: Please post the full traceback - we can't tell on which line the exception is raised. FWIW if it's on the "print" statement, your problem is with your stdout stream not handling unicode (BS always return unicode), so you'll have to do the proper encoding according to your system settings (or fix your system settings as to handle utf8).

Comment: errors. encode('ascii', 'ignore') solved my problem ;) many thx!